# how to get list of colors in android studio for mac? (ctrl q on windows)

Tags: android-studio, dart, colors

Coding dart In android studios when you write colors: Colors. choose a color and then press ctrl q on windows you get a list of colors with corresponding numbers you can choose from like:

colors: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[200] for example. How to I get that list on a mac? No shortcut seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on three dots and open up quick documentation or press F1 button after typing Colors.[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, you actually just have to do e.g purple.shade100

There is no shortcut I believe for mac, but you can do . and it'll pull up options